# Does double buffering for the purpose of vertex streaming do anything in webgl?

Tags: webgl

I am trying to render as many moving objects as I can with WebGL and I am updating objects position by glBufferData/glBufferSubData each frame.I found that it is recommended to use a double buffer to reduce synchronization issues between GPU and CPU: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData.html and https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming and google's [webgl optimizationg slides](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/12AGAUmElB0oOBgbEEBfhABkIMCL3CUX7kdAPLuwZ964/edit?pli=1#slide=id.i0).

So I have implemented double buffering and it is drawing as expected. However, there was no performance gains. (In fact it made it slower) So I am curious if the double buffer technique described in the above 3 documents is approriate for webgl.

Here is basically what I am doing (capture by webgl inspector):

frame X:

[image]

Frame X+1:

[image]

Comment: glBufferSubData hit the performance as there could be some draw call finish before the other started. As CPU and GPU run parallel. Try to reduce your glBufferSubData call probably that could give you boost with performance.

Comment: I cannot reduce the amount of glBufferSubData calls as all the new data needs to be uploaded to GPU. Unless you are meaning something else?

Comment: You could reduce your vertexbuffer count by using `UNSIGNED INT`([widely supported](http://webglstats.com/#highcharts-66)) indexbuffers, another option depending on what you do to your vertex buffers is doing the transforms directly on the gpu within the vertex shader.

Comment: Based on my tests, (im drawing many many quads with its own unique position per frame) reducing the vertex buffer count does not accomplish anything. Infact, smaller batch size may perform better especially if you draw the buffer some CPU cycles behind the upload. Like upload to buffer B, draw buffer A, upload to buffer C, draw buffer B. Doing transforms on the GPU would be nice but it is not an option for the framework im writing for.